# Assignment Operator with Template classes - no acceptable conversion, C++

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

I build a template class that is supposed to represent a thread-local pointer.

```
template <class T>
class ThreadLocalPointer {
    public:
        T& operator*() {
            return *_map[std::this_thread::get_id()];
        }

        T* operator->() {
            return _map[std::this_thread::get_id()];
        }
        ThreadLocalPointer<T>& operator=(const T* right) {
            _map[std::this_thread::get_id()] = right;
            return *this;
        }

        T* get() {
            return _map[std::this_thread::get_id()];
        }
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, T*> _map;  
};
```

Instance of the class:

```
ThreadLocalPointer<PacketClientHeader*> _incomingBuffer;
```

And finally, where I want to use my assignment operator

```
_incomingBuffer = (PacketClientHeader*)malloc(MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
```

The code won't compile:

```
    no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'PacketClientHeader *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Edit: Included the full template

Comment: You don't need `<T>` in the operator, if what you are showing is inside the class declaration.

Comment: Isn't the point to return itself so that things like

_incomingBuffer = _outgoingBuffer = _otherBuffer;

work?

Comment: Yeah, but if your operator is in the class declaration, and assuming the class is a template with template parameter `T`, then you don't need `<T>` in the return of the operator. I am not saying it will fix the problem though.

Comment: Oh! Well that's helpful regardless.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be that here:

```
ThreadLocalPointer<PacketClientHeader*> _incomingBuffer;
```

the template argument `T` is `PacketClientHeader*`, and here:

```
ThreadLocalPointer<T>& operator=(const T* right) { .... }
```

your operator is taking a `const T*`, which would resolve to `const PacketClientHeader**`. You then try to assign from a `PacketClientHeader*` here:

```
_incomingBuffer = (PacketClientHeader*)malloc(MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
```

and no suitable operator is found. Without knowing more details of the class it is difficult to suggest a solution, but it could be as simple as using

```
    ThreadLocalPointer<PacketClientHeader> _incomingBuffer;
```

or declaring the assignment operator as

```
ThreadLocalPointer& operator=(const T& right) { .... }
```

Comment: It looks like your hypothesis is correct.  As for the solution, it looks like it's a little more than that though.